# How to access View-Propperties in the ViewModel, using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, properties, caliburn.micro, window-chrome

Until now I only used the basic features of the Caliburn.Micro Framework. But now I want and need to to get deeper into it.

Now I have the case that I need to access properties of the view (a Window) inside its view model.

The details are the following:
I customize the shell-window, using Microsoft's Window-Chrome (NuGet-Package: Microsoft.Windows.Chrome).
Now I need to check the value of the window's WindowState-Property, to set the property bound to its ResizeBorderThickness-property correctly.

How can I do that with the Caliburn.Micro Framework?

Additional infos:
.NET Framework: 4.5;
Caliburn.Micro: 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't directly access view properties in a view model. This effectively breaks the MVVM pattern and what it is all about. A view model shouldn't have any dependency upon the view.

What you could do is to bind the `WindowState` property of the window to a `bool?` source property of your view model and then perform any logic in the setter of the latter.

Comment: Basicly I know how to bind properties.
My Problem is that this time the property I need is set by the view and not by the view model, so the direction of data flow is reversed.

Comment: The view model needs to set a property of the view is the same thing as the view model setting a property of itself that is bound to a property of the view. This is how data binding works.

Comment: Okay, so I don't have to define that as a ToWay-Binding?

Comment: In my case its the other way around, so I will have to make that a TwoWay-binding. I will try that and report the result later.

Comment: If the target property in the view to update the source property of the view model, the mode of the binding should be set to TwoWay.